# Using kerberos authentication with WebAPI in .NET core

Tags: authentication, iis, .net-core, kerberos

I have built a .net core application that is being hosted by IIS, and I want to force a certain API endpoint to use negotiate authentication only.

So I tried adding the following to web.config:

```xml
  <location path="~/api/v1/authentication/sso">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

But when I open the url, no authentication happens and I just get the 200 response back from the server.

Comment: The actual IIS configuration system (and how to write proper location tags) is far beyond what you imagined, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/the-configuration-system-in-iis-7 So when you wrote invalid elements like that, it won't work. You should run such endpoints in a separate site/application and enable Windows authentication via IIS Manager.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to tell me, but if you are referring to the locked sections, I have unlocked the relevant sections. Trying to overrule locked sections have given me 500 errors in the past, not ignored settings. Windows authentication is enabled for the whole site, as is anonymous, I just need to disable anonymous for the relevant path

Comment: The value you gave to path is invalid.

Comment: In what way is it invalid though? The same path format has worked fine for other applications..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the build-in asp.net core auth attribute.

set the following to have authorization on every Controller

```
 services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
```

and use [AllowAnonymous] for those where you don't need it.

for more detail you could refer this below article:

[Introduction to authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

[Simple authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Sounds like that will be incompatible with identityserver4?

Comment: if you use identity server 4 that means your web API should check the identity server token instead of using current server's windows auth.in my opinion identity server support windows auth.do you want to enable the windows Kerberos auth for identity server?

Comment: internal users should be able to use SSO rather than having to input a password, but external users cannot use SSO. I am building a login portal based on IdentityServer, so what I am wanting to do is to automatically detect the user being kerberos enabled when they get directed to the login page from an application - but the thing is, I need the internal users to stop by the login page rather than just silently be logged in because the user is supposed to be able to manually log in as a different user if needs be

Comment: Just for posterity: I ended up just leaving Windows and Anonymous enabled and returning a 401 manually from the appropriate controller methods, to trigger the negotiate that way.